# int pointer expressions

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
   int a[]={0,1,2,3,4};
   int *p[]={a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4};
   int **ptr=p;

   ptr++;
   printf("%d %d %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-a,**ptr);

   *ptr++;
   printf("%d %d %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-a,**ptr);

   *++ptr;
   printf("%d %d %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-a,**ptr);

   ++*ptr;
   printf("%d %d %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-a,**ptr);
return 0;
}
```

The answer for this program is 
1 1 1

2 2 2

3 3 3

3 4 4

with gcc.But why is the output for the first printf giving 1 1 1  shouldn't it be 4 4 1?
lets say if p=6004 and and ptr would be 6004 and ptr++ would be 6008.then ptr-p should give 4.pls correct me.thanks..

Comment: You have a bad case of Undefined behavior with `ptr-p` and all bets are off from that point on. So no telling what the output may be.

Comment: I thought it was correct.What seems to the problem with the expression ptr-p? please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of pointer arithmetic is not exactly the result of their address arithmetic. The output should be `((address of ptr) - (address of p)) / (sizeof(pointed_type))`
For example:

```
int a[] = {0,1,2,3,4};
int *p=a;
int *p2 = p+1;
printf("%d",p2-p)     // will print 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified it a little to be certain. The point here is that subtracting pointer returns the number of units i.e. address / size of pointer, not plain difference of address locations.

```
   printf("ptr before %p\n", ptr);
   ptr++;
   printf("ptr after %p and p %p\n", ptr, p);
   printf("%ld %ld %d\n",ptr-p,*ptr-a,**ptr);
```

On my 64 bit machine, the printed addresses are 8 locations apart with just a single ++. On a 32 bit machine this would be 4. But still the arithmetic difference would return 1.